# How to split the elements ​of an array of strings if they are equal?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Good day,

I currently have a string array like this:

```
string[] array = {"aa","bb","cc","dd","aa","cc","ee","ff","aa","bb"}
```

I would like to be able to get the positions that are the same from the same string [], example:

```
string[] a = {"aa","aa","aa"}
string[] b = {"bb","bb"}
string[] c = {"cc","cc"}
string[] d = {"dd"}
string[] e = {"ee"}
string[] f = {"ff"}
```

It should be noted that the elements of the parent matrix always change and are not always the same.

I tried with linq, but I don't get what I'm looking for.

this was my attempt with linq:

```
array.Where(x => array.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Thanks for help me!

Comment: How about: `var c = array.Where(x => x.Contains('c')).ToArray()`? Dictionary would do better than many local variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite seeing what you ask for, the result you want is pretty limited an not useful to work with later on. You should take advantage of using the `GroupBy` in linq and then when you need something find it in that collection.

```
// your array
string[] array = {"aa","bb","cc","dd","aa","cc","ee","ff","aa","bb"};

// group by value
var groupedValues = array.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();

// get the "aa" group if exist
var aa = groupedValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "aa");

// check if the group was found
if(aa != null)
{
    // get all "aa" values in that group. This return this collection based on your inpit{ "aa", "aa", "aa" } 
    var allaaValues = aa.ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1, but just note that the ToList() calls aren't necessary - you can call `GroupBy` directly on the array, and you can call `FirstOrDefault` directly on the `IGrouping` returned by GroupBy.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Well the `.ToList` to me is necessary for performance purpose otherwise since he need to make this call in his example 6 times so it would perform the grouping 7 times if we leave `IEnumerable` while using `.ToList` will only perform it once.

Comment: Franck, thanks for your answer, but always the elements of the mother matrix change and are not the same always.

Comment: @JonathanBurgosGio And your point is ? this will always group by the same value exactly like your example no matter the value it contains. Be it `string`, `double`, `int`, etc. All that need to change is the `FirstOrDefault()` if you do not know what is grouped just query the group to get what was grouped together like `groupedValues.Select(x=>x.Key).ToList()`

Comment: @Franck: the first ToList, on the array, is meaningless. The second, after `GroupBy`, can be useful to avoid repeated iterations with `FirstOrDefault`, but this might not be relevant if the use case is a bit different - for instance, calling `ToDictionary` on the `IGrouping` to create the mapping:
`array.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g)`

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Oh yeah didn't noticed that one on array. I write it by habit I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is a solution you were looking for, good luck!

```
string[] array = { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "aa", "cc", "ee", "ff", "aa", "bb" };
var splittedArray = new List<string[]>();

foreach (var strItem in array)
{
    //Don't iterating duplicates
    if (splittedArray.Any(si => si.Contains(strItem))) continue;
    //if more then one item exists in the array getting those identic items and adding to the array list
    if (array.Count(si => si.Equals(strItem)) > 0)
    {
        var identicItems = array
                .Where(i => i.Equals(strItem))
                .ToArray();

        splittedArray.Add(identicItems);
    }
    else // Adding single item as a new array with this item
    {
        splittedArray.Add(new string[] { strItem });
    }
}
```